# Wifi Media Streaming to TV without Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming

I've been using Plex now for awhile to watch video saved on my laptop on my LG TV. I start Plex on my laptop and my TV recognizes it as a media server. It's been working great but my only complaint is that if my internet cuts out for even a second it cuts the video on TV. I don't understand why Plex should need internet access, it should be capable of streaming over my WiFi without a net connection.

Any other possible solutions to stream over a local network without requiring an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

it is dependent on internet for authentication.

https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/142929/plex-without-internet-access

You might find more meaningful information on plex forums and even on Google